# How to list down all the dataflow jobs using python API

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

My use case involves fetching the job id of all streaming dataflow jobs present in my project and cancel it. Update the sources for my dataflow job and re-run it.

I am trying to achieve this using python. I did not come across any useful documentation until now.
I thought of using python's library subprocess to execute the gcloud commands as a workaround. But again I was not able to store the result and use it.

Can somebody please guide me as what is the best way of doing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to using the rest API directly, you can use the generated Python bindings for the API in [google-api-python-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/master/docs/start.md).  For simple calls it doesn't add that much value, but when passing in many parameters it can be easier to work with than a raw HTTP library.

With that library, the jobs list call would look like

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import google.auth
credentials, project_id = google.auth.default(scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])
df_service = build('dataflow', 'v1b3', credentials=credentials)
response = df_service.projects().locations().jobs().list(
  project_id=project_id,
  location='<region>').execute()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use directly the [Dataflow rest api](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.jobs/list) like this

```
    from google.auth.transport.requests import AuthorizedSession
    import google.auth

    base_url = 'https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/'

    credentials, project_id = google.auth.default(scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])
    project_id = 'PROJECT_ID'
    location = 'europe-west1'
    authed_session = AuthorizedSession(credentials)
    response = authed_session.request('GET', f'{base_url}{project_id}/locations/{location}/jobs')
    print(response.json())
```

You have to import the google-auth dependency.

You can also add the query parameter `?filter=ACTIVE` to get only the active dataflow, that can match with your streaming jobs.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the full Trinity of options that you have:

1. using the REST API directly ([answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62996558/3937850) @guillaume blaquiere)
2. using API Discovery Service ([answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63004940/3937850) by @danielm)
3. using [google-cloud-dataflow-client](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-dataflow-client/) python SDK library (this answer by myself)

Install the client library:

```bash
pip install google-cloud-dataflow-client
```

then

```py
from google.cloud.dataflow_v1beta3 import JobsV1Beta3Client, ListJobsRequest

client = JobsV1Beta3Client()
request = ListJobsRequest(
    project_id="<PROJECT_ID>",
    location="<LOCATION>", # won't work without location
    filter="ACTIVE", # remove if you also want finished
)
jobs = client.list_jobs(request=request)
for job in jobs:
    print(job)
```

It looks like you can only get jobs up to 30 days in the past.